# T-SQL Select columns from one table where id in another table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I asked this question some time back: [Adding attachments to taks records in T_SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28910166/3482632)
and got a perfect answer to my question.

However I need to take this one step further. If I have the following (based on the previous question's answer)

```
SELECT TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskType 
FROM Tasks 
WHERE TaskType = 1 [FIRST-TABLE]
```

I want be able to then select

```
SELECT AttachmentId, TaskId, [FileName], FileLocation 
FROM TaskAttachments 
[WHERE TaskId IN FIRST-TABLE] ;
```

and I need to be able to return both tables to asp.net

I can write a query which does this:

```
SELECT AttachmentId, TaskId, [FileName], FileLocation 
FROM TaskAttachments 
WHERE TaskId EXISTS IN (SELECT TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskType 
                        FROM Tasks
                        WHERE TaskType = 1);
```

My actual queries are much longer with lots of joins and so this second query becomes very long and this seems convoluted and requires selecting the same data twice.

Is there a better way than this by using the actual data returned from the first `SELECT`?

(BTW, please forgive any syntax errors. This is just for quick illustration, my actual code works fine!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use common table expression in this situation:

```
;with cte as(SELECT TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskType FROM Tasks)
SELECT AttachmentId, TaskId, [FileName], FileLocation 
FROM TaskAttachments where TaskID in(select TaskId from cte where TaskType = 1)
```

**EDIT:**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] = '#tasks') BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #tasks;
END;

--save to temp table
SELECT TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskType into #tasks FROM Tasks

--select from temp table
SELECT TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskType FROM #tasks

--select from second table using temp table
SELECT AttachmentId, TaskId, [FileName], FileLocation 
FROM TaskAttachments where TaskID in(select TaskId from #tasks where TaskType = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it appears to only return one result set. Am I missing something?. I need to return the results set from Tasks AND TaskAttachments as two separate tables.

Comment: What does it mean? If you want 2 separate tables then write 2 separate statements

Comment: I am trying to get a list of tasks first with a tasktype of 1. Then I want to get a table of attachments where the taskId's match only those in the first table, without having to write the whole select out again for the second SELECT.

Comment: This is great. The only issue I have is that if I run this a second time, I get an error: There is already an object named '#tasks' in the database.  If I try DROP #tasks, after the above statements, I get another error: Unknown object type '#tasks' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

Comment: If you call in one session then add drop table #tasks in the end, if sessions are different it will be dropped automatically

Comment: Or you can check at the beginning if it exists the drop. See edits

Answer (score 0):

Joining the two tables perhaps instead of using an EXISTS clause?

```
SELECT ta.AttachmentId, ta.TaskId, ta.FileName, ta.FileLocation 
FROM TaskAttachments ta INNER JOIN Tasks t ON ta.TaskId = t.TaskId 
WHERE t.TaskType = 1;
```

That would result in a shorter query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AttachmentId, TaskAttachments.TaskId, [FileName], FileLocation    
  FROM TaskAttachments    
  JOIN Tasks 
    on TaskAttachments.TaskId = Tasks.TaskId    
   and Tasks.TaskType = 1
```